# Write keycode to console. Repeatedly

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard

I'm having a small mental block: I've got a javascript function in html that writes the keycode when a key is pressed. I've got it hooked up to a function that tells me exactly what character and keycode is pressed (not included).

My question is how do I modify the code to print up keypress after keypress after keypress. At the moment it does just the one and then that's that.

There's a rather nicer version of what I'm doing here on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/), with the [code here](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/mPgoYJ) 
Admittedly the latter is running JS Babel which might be the difference. However, I need to do this in **pure Javascript**.

Bonus points: is keypress one word or two ;)

```
</script>
function check_keycode(e)
{
    var keycode;

    if (window.event)
    {
        keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e)
    {
        keycode = e.which;
    }
    document.write("keycode: " + keycode);
    //console.log("keycode: " + keycode);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're basically asking how to append to the document instead of replacing its contents. This is the reason why people shouldn't use `document.write`, ever. Replace it with `document.body.innerHTML += "keycode: " + keycode + "<br>";` (you also have a closing script tag at the start of your script)

Comment: Rereading this, I misunderstood slightly. To do what you want, add something like `<pre id="output"></pre>` to your `<body>`. Then use `output.textContent = "keycode: " + keycode;` (also, you want to write to the document, not the console)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want some thing like this. I tried with chrome console.

HTML

```
<p id="log"></p>
```

JS:

```
const log = document.getElementById('log');

document.addEventListener('keypress', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
  log.textContent += ` ${e.key}`;
}
```